# Creating an ad-hoc unit for siunitx

Tags: siunitx

Is there a way to create a one-off unit for the `siunitx` package on the fly, so to say? I mean, without the `\DeclareSIUnit` command. The purpose is to make it work with the `\per` parsing, as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=reciprocal}
\begin{document}

\SI{1}{\meter\per\second} % works fine

\SI{1}{cycle\per\second} % does not obey per-mode=reciprocal

\SI{1}{{round tuit}\per\second} % ditto

\end{document}
```

So what I'm after is something I can use in `\SI{1}{\foo{round tuit}\per\second}`.

Comment: Judging by the manual you're not supposed to use units on-the-fly.

Comment: Currently 'no' as _ad hoc_ units feel to me to go with _ad hoc_ formatting, but of course you can log a request

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with so far is (ab)using `\of`, like this:

```
\sisetup{qualifier-mode=combine}
\DeclareSIUnit{\foo}{\relax}

\SI{1}{\foo\of{round\ tuit}\per\second}
```